# Add button to close all tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add a close button after the tab. That close button should close all the opened tab. How can closing all tabs can be done? There should be a close button at the end of the tabpane the functionality is to close the tabs that are open. How can this be done and what is the functionality to do this action.

Link - https://jsfiddle.net/t5q37nbe/2/

```js
const { Tabs, Button } = antd
const { TabPane } = Tabs

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      focusingPaneKey: '1',
      openingPaneKeys: ['1'],
    }
  }

  openPane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (!state.openingPaneKeys.includes(paneKey)) {
        state.openingPaneKeys = [...state.openingPaneKeys, paneKey]
      }

      state.focusingPaneKey = paneKey
      return state
    })
  }

  closePane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (paneKey === state.focusingPaneKey) {
        const paneKeyIndex = state.openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
        state.focusingPaneKey = state.openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1]
      }

      state.openingPaneKeys = state.openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey)

      return state
    })
  }

  handleTabsEdit = (key, action) => {
    if (action === 'remove') {
      this.closePane(key)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { panes } = this.props
    const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

    return (
      <div className="tab-section">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
            <Button key={key} onClick={() => this.openPane(key)}>
              ADD Tab-{key}
            </Button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.openPane}
          activeKey={this.state.focusingPaneKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.handleTabsEdit}
        >
          {this.state.openingPaneKeys
            .map((key) => panes[key])
            .map((pane) => (
              <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                {pane.content}
              </TabPane>
            ))}
            <div><BiWindowClose /></div>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const panes = {
  1: { key: '1', title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
  2: { key: '2', title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
  3: { key: '3', title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
}

ReactDOM.render(<App panes={panes} />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pm52Lhnr/ - seems to run when I add reactdom

Comment: @mplungjan it is running now, The second issue that I have is to close all the tabs on clicking close button.

Comment: Please change your question then. If the code is running you only have the tab question, which I do not understand anyway. You can close the tabs in the fiddle

Comment: @mplungjan The code is same, logic here is on clicking Add tab-1, tab-1 with content opens similarly for other tabs as well.

Comment: @mplungjan I want to add a button that closes all the opened tabs.

Comment: PS: Please fork the fiddle I made you and use that instead. It is confusing you use my fiddle and one day I may delete it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243782/discussion-between-userd-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0):

This should add a 'Close All Tabs' button. When this button is clicked, all the tabs will be closed.

**Code Sample**

```
<div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
  {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
    <Button key={key} onClick={() => this.openPane(key)}>
      ADD Tab-{key}
    </Button>
  ))}
  <Button
    onClick={() => keysOfPane.forEach(
      id => this.handleTabsEdit(id, 'remove')
    )}
  >
    Close All Tabs
  </Button>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

The `onClick` event iterates over the `keys` array and invokes the `handleTabsEdit` for each key with the `action` as `remove`.

This was tested on [mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pm52Lhnr/): https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pm52Lhnr/

Please take a copy as this may not remain available for later.

Comment: You could fork my fiddle